# HTML 5 Required field validation Check using Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[image]

HTML 5 provide "required" attribute.
For Email field, It give different message based on email entered.
I want to check these message using Selenium webdriver, Please Help.

Please check the image.

Comment: Please check image by clicking on "enter image description here".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to verify text in message generated by Constraint Validation API in HTML5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432490/how-to-verify-text-in-message-generated-by-constraint-validation-api-in-html5)